# How do I turn a 2-column csv into a json list of the key/value pairs using python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv like this:

| key | spanish |
| --- | --- |
| no | no |
| yes | is |
| why | porque |

I want to make it into a json like this:

```
{
   "no": "no",
   "yes": "si",
   "why": "porque"
}
```

All the examples I have found online create JSON's kind of like this:

```
{
    "no": {
        "key": "no",
        "Spanish": "no"
    }
}
```

I would like to write a python script that will create the simple key/value pairs in a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import json

myDict = {}
with open('path/to/csv') as iFile:
 myCSV = csv.reader(iFile)
 for line in myCSV:
   k,v = line
   myDict[k] = v

myJSON = json.dumps(myDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Load you csv to dataframe, then use this:

`df.set_index('key')['spanish'].to_json('path/to/jsonfile.json')`

Neatly save the dataframe in json format.